# openrefine how remove certain words from the end of each cell

Tags: openrefine

i have a column in openrefine, which has cells with content like:

```
This dog is a great dog.
This cat is a great cat,
```

i would like to remove the words dog, cat from the end of each cell (if punctuation could be removed also, it would be great).

i have tried with

\bdog\s*$
but i get errors, or no replacement done
I am using openrefine 3.3.

```
value.replace(\bdog|\bcat\s*$,'')
```

error i get:

```
Parsing error at offset 14: Missing number, string, identifier, regex, or parenthesized expression
```

desired output:

```
This dog is a great
This cat is a great
```

also, it would be great if i could also remove all characters in the end like " : , . (actually i am looking for a regex to cluster publishers -librarian data) so if you could suggest words i should remove from the end of the cells i would be grateful

Comment: In OR a regex must ne enclosed in //, like in value.replace(/youregex/,'')

Comment: could you please also elaborate on how would you approach the problem i have, which is i want to remove all punctuation, and common words found in publishers' data, in a bibliographic set. Stop words i have come up so far are 'and co' ltd

Comment: Could you try this? `value.replace(/\p{Punct}$/, '').replace(/cat|dog/,'')`

Comment: i have tried the above, but for some reason it says working for more than a day, with no results so far

Answer (score 0):

I combined Ettore answer with the `split()` function `value.split(' ')[-1]` that select the last part word of a string.

The results is :
`replace(value,value.split(' ')[-1],'') + value.split(' ')[-1].replace(/cat|dog/,'')`

where

- `replace(value,value.split(' ')[-1],'')` select your string expect the last work
- `value.split(' ')[-1].replace(/cat|dog/,'')` replace the last word with nothing if it contains `cat` or `dog`.

Note that the expression is working because of the punctuation at the end of the string. Not a perfect solution but you may be able to build something from here.